# AWS Redshift - Set part size while unloading to s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

While unloading a large result set to s3, redshift automatically split the files into multiple parts. Is there a way to set the size of each part while unloading?

Comment: As of today, no. Its set to 6.2Gb and can't be changed. You could use limits to only select some of the data.

Answer (score 2):

When unload, you can use maxfilesize to indicate the maximum size of the file. 
For exampe:

```
    unload ('select * from venue')
to 's3://mybucket/unload/' 
iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::0123456789012:role/MyRedshiftRole'
maxfilesize 1 gb;
```

[From here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UNLOAD_command_examples.html)

Answer (score -1):

Redshift by default unloads data into multiple files according to the number of slices in your cluster. So, if you have 4 slices in the cluster, you would have 4 files written by each cluster concurrently.

Here is short answer to your question from the Documentation. Go [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UNLOAD.html) for details.

"By default, UNLOAD writes data in parallel to multiple files, according to the number of slices in the cluster. The default option is ON or TRUE. If PARALLEL is OFF or FALSE, UNLOAD writes to one or more data files serially, sorted absolutely according to the ORDER BY clause, if one is used. The maximum size for a data file is 6.2 GB. So, for example, if you unload 13.4 GB of data, UNLOAD creates the following three files."

I hope this helps.